# Fastest method for freeing up memory allocated to a hash table in C

Tags: c

Im looking for a faster method of freeing up memory allocated to a hash table in my code.  What I've written below works but I want to know if there is another method that would accomplish the task faster.

```
bool unload(void)
{
    if (load)
    {
        node* temp;
        node* crawler;

        for(int n = 0; n < TABLESIZE; n++)
        {   
            if (hashtable[n] != NULL)
            {    
                // If only 1 node free it
                crawler = hashtable[n];
                while (crawler != NULL)
                {
                    temp = crawler->next;
                    free(crawler);
                    crawler = temp;

                }
                // free last node in list
                temp = crawler;
                free(temp);
            }        
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;    
}
```

Comment: I think that http://codereview.stackexchange.com is exactly intended for this sort of “my code works but is there another method?” question.

Comment: To free(NULL) will happen after the while loop in your code

Comment: I agree with the first comment (more suitable for codereview), and in addition, as far as I know, `true` and `false` are not part of the C standard, but the C++ standard.

Comment: Fastest way to free is not to free at all. Bind all nodes you want to free into linked list, and reuse them again. More general way is to make pool of nodes, and take node from pool and return it back.

Comment: If you want to ask a question on [codereview.se], I suggest that you post your entire hashtable implementation rather than just this function.

Answer (score 4):

```
        while (crawler != NULL)
        {
        …
        }
        // free last node in list
        temp = crawler;
        free(temp);
```

When the loop exits, `crawler` is equal to `NULL`. Therefore, while it is perfectly acceptable to pass it to `free()`, you can save some time by not doing so.

Comment: Perfect actually halved the unload time.